# Opening all outside-app links in a system browser

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ng-map

I have an Ionic 1 app which includes Google Maps via the ngMap directive. This works great.

What *doesn't* work great is when the user clicks on the "Credits" element in the map and the entire app is redirected away to the Google map credits page- and because it's an Ionic app, there is no way for the user to go back.

Is there a way in Ionic / Angular (not jQuery) to intercept arbitrary links like these so that they open in an in-app or system browser?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is done as follows:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpgrdN

```
function isExternal(href) {
  return true;
}
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var maybeA = $(e.target).closest('a');
  if (maybeA.length && isExternal(maybeA[0].getAttribute('href'))) {
      // window.open()
      console.log('prevented');
      e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Used jQuery `closest` function, if no jQuery on page standalone implementation is here [DOM / pure JavaScript solution to jQuery.closest() implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100853/dom-pure-javascript-solution-to-jquery-closest-implementation)