# Handling event delegation with children

Tags: javascript, html, event-delegation

For efficiency I'm tracking the click event against my `nav` rather than each `li`. However, each `li` has a set of `span` tags inside them. I need to manipulate the clicked `li` and get it's position (index). However, my `e.target` is showing my `span` tag rather than the `li`. I understand why but I'm not sure who to prevent it. My html is:

```
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="num">1</span><span class="text">Contact</span></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and my js is basically:

```
  const nav = document.getElementById('nav');
  nav.addEventListener('click',navClick,false);
  function navClick(e) {
    console.log(e);
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
```

I know I can use `closest('li')` to see if I'm in the `li` but that doesn't seem to be giving me what I want when I need to grab the `li` index, add/remove classes, etc.

Comment: See my answer here, this might hep: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48683414/448144 The path stores the actual HTML element reference, so you should be able to extract the index or anything else from the parent `li` or use jQuery but without knowing what you mean exactly by `but that doesn't seem to be giving me what I want` it's hard to pinpoint which solution might fit best.

Comment: do you want to use jquery?

Comment: @Dipakchavda trying to keep this pure JS. I can do this with jQuery in my sleep, lol

Comment: @Nope I'll need to get the index but logging `e.target.closest('li')` returns `<li></li>` which I don't think I can really use to extract location.

Comment: Why not add a data-index attribute to the LI elements?

Comment: @dcp3450 `e.target.closest('li').previousSibling` Sounds like looping through the previous siblings might work ► https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913927/get-child-node-index - Though extend that answer with a node type check as `previousSibling` also `refers to a whitespace text node rather than the actual element the author intended to get.`